# Will it cause problem if I never shutdown my PC and use `suspend` instead of it?

Tags: suspend

This has been always a question for me, is it good or bad to leave PC suspended for a long time (a week for example)? Is it good or bad to `never` shut down PC and instead of it use suspend? Will there be any hardware/software problems? Will hard disk shut down during suspension? Will mother board shut down? Will there be any heat problem with CPU?

Any kind of helps would be appreciated.

Comment: I do this on a regular basis with no ill affects. The PC will draw a very small amount of power while in stasis. You will be prompted to restart sometimes due to installed updates.

Comment: is `very small amount` so that this can be done with laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it might a good idea to restart when Ubuntu asks you too (e.g. kernel installation), but generally it should not be a problem to just use suspend-only mode of operation.

As for the 'for week' part – it depends – the computer will draw small amount of power (as does your telly, etc.), so if you leave it unplugged, you might found it dead after some period of time because of battery would be drained.  How much time is that is hard to generally say.